# Python Django Unable to display two forms in one template

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates, view

I have a problem to display two forms in one template. If I delete one of these forms `{'form': form}` or `{'obj': obj}` from my views.py the remaining form is displayed correctly. It is the first time that I need to use two form in one template so I don't know if my views.py is correct.

this my views.py

```
def Form(request):
        form = ResgisterStud(request.POST)
        obj = SomeForm(request.POST)
        if request.recaptcha_is_valid and form.is_valid()and request.method=='POST' and 'student' in request.POST:
                form.save(commit=False)
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Saved student')
                return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form}, {'obj': obj})
        if request.method == 'POST' and 'disponnibility' in request.POST:
            obj.save(commit=False)
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Saved Dispo')
            return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form}, {'obj': obj})
        else:
                return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form}, {'obj': obj})
```

my form.html

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ obj.as_p }}
    <input name="disponnibility" type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

 <form action="{% url "form" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                {{ form.Nom|add_class:"form-control" }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                {{ form.Prenom|add_class:"form-control" }}
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                {{ form.Telephone|add_class:"form-control" }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                                <button name="student" class="btn" type="submit">Submit Now</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is nothing to do with forms, but simply the syntax of the `render` function. It takes a single dictionary as the context, not two; you need to put both objects in the same dict.

```
return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form, 'obj': obj})
```